# Remove number of data frames from list of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

Say I have a list of 480 data frames in R. How would I remove 16 data frames from the list every 32 iterations? For example, I want to remove c(33:48) and remove c(81:96) and so forth.

Comment: `a <- list(mtcars, mtcars*2, mtcars*3, mtcars*4); a <- a[-c(2, 4)]`. In your case, `b <- 1:480; b[(b %/% 32) %% 2 == 0]; your_list <- your_list[b]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend `subset`:

```r
x <- as.list(1:480)
subset(x,c(rep(TRUE,32),rep(FALSE,16)))

#Alternatively rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),times = c(32,16))
```

Note that the logical vector is automatically recycled (repeated) for the length of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a vector of the indices you want to remove and then use negative indexing to drop them:

```
to_remove = unlist(lapply(48 * 1:10, \(x) x - (15:0)))

## check it looks right
to_remove
#   [1]  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96 129
#  [34] 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 225 226
#  [67] 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 321 322 323
# [100] 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 417 418 419 420
# [133] 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480

## remove them
your_list = your_list[-to_remove]
```

Or you could make a logical vector of what you want to keep and use that to index

```
keep = rep(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times = c(32, 16)), 10)
your_list = your_list[keep]

## another way
keep = (1:480 - 1) %% 48 < 32
your_list = your_list[keep]
```

Comment: As I note in my answer, no need to repeat the logical vector, it's automatically recycled.

Comment: I dislike depending on recycling except for length 1 inputs.

Comment: In that case, consider `length.out = `?

Comment: That would also work

Answer (score 0):

you can covert the list into a data.frame and subset rows that are not the last 16 values of each set.

```
ls2 <- lapply(1:480, function(x) list(as.data.frame(x)))

df <- do.call(rbind, ls2) |>
      transform(v2 = rep(1:48, 10)) |>
      subset(!v2 %in% 33:48 )
```

Edit based on @gregor comments below

Simply make a vector of repeating 1 to 48 and filter where it doesn't equal 33 to 48.

```
idx = rep(1:48, 10) 
ls3 <- ls2[!idx %in% 33:48]
```

Comment: Conversions and combining are very expensive operations, assuming the inputs are even conformable--the data frames in the list may all have different dimensions! You can use the same logic directly on the list (much like in my answer) - `idx = rep(1:48, 10)` then `ls2[!idx %in% 33:48]`

Comment: a much simpler solution!